# Supress spammy discord log

Tags: logs, gnome-shell, discord

Everytime I open discord (installed using deb package), my log always spammed with these kind of message every second:

```
Jun 25 20:14:20 pop2104 gnome-shell[102661]: [2022-06-25 20:14:20.833] [102901] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
Jun 25 20:14:20 pop2104 gnome-shell[102661]: [2022-06-25 20:14:20.950] [102901] (device_info_linux.cc:45): NumberOfDevices
Jun 25 20:14:20 pop2104 gnome-shell[102661]: [2022-06-25 20:14:20.950] [102901] (device_info_linux.cc:78): GetDeviceName
```

note: previously was using flatpak version of discord, and it has similar problem

How to suppress this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall disable debug logging in settings, "Voice & Video" and this option will be at the bottom, as mentioned in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Discord#Discord_spams_systemd_journal